# Dynamic Sender Profile randomly works

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder

This is such a strange case. I created a dynamic sender profile which randomly shows the right sender and otherwise shows the default one. I will tell you step by step what I did:

- Creating a journey with entry event: API Event.
- Created a Data Extension with NO primary key, because there is no unique value in this data extension. And added the right fields containing the following fields: CreatedByName and CreatedByEmail.
- Salesforce API call which sends all the data needed to the created data extension including the two fields named above.
- Email is created with a HTML block with customer key: "e-signature-reminder" and contains the following code:

```
%%[
var @fromName, @fromEmail
   set @fromName = AttributeValue("CreatedByName") 
   set @fromEmail = AttributeValue("CreatedByEmail") 
]%%
```

- Sender profile is created as follows:

From Name:

```
%%[ContentBlockByKey("e-signature-reminder")]%%%%=v(@fromName)=%%
```

From Email:

```
%%[ContentBlockByKey("e-signature-reminder")]%%%%=v(@fromEmail)=%%
```

- Within the journey added the email with the HTML block. As Sender Profile, I select the sender profile which i just created.
- Activated the journey.

The result is random. Sometimes it shows me the: populated fields CreatedByName and CreatedByEmail and sometimes it doesn't. The email addresses which appear in the CreatedByEmail field are email addresses part of the validated domain so no problems there. What do i do wrong?

Comment: May be a dumb question, but you have verified that those 2 fields are filled in correctly in every record prior to send time, right?

Comment: The API call sends the data to the data extension and THEN fires the journey. That's how it works I assume?

Comment: Have you verified in the DE that those fields are passed though?

Comment: The values are in the DE, so yes.

Answer (score 0):

Is this DE associated to allcontacts (Contact Builder)?This happens when your association with the subscriberkey is 1 to N, so SFMC will populate the first result they find in the DE.

It happens the same with the filter criteria when you use a data extension as a entry of a Journey

Comment: ContactId relates to subscriber on Subscriber Key. So yes it does.